# Bijectivity of radial projection

Tags: general-topology

So I'm trying to show that the boundary of a simplex is homeomorphic to a sphere, and I want to do it by radial projection. But it's turning out to be surprisingly difficult. Intuitively, it is clear that any ray that extends from the origin must intersect the boundary exactly once. But I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously. Radial projection seems to be a common technique, but I can never find the details! My textbook claims that it is possible but does not elaborate, and I've looked around on this site too but without much success. So here's what I need help with:

> Let $K$ be an $n$-simplex, and assume that the origin is an interior point. Prove that the radial projection map $h(x) = \dfrac{x}{||x||}$ from the boundary of $K$ to the $(n-1)$-sphere is a bijection.

I think I've managed to show surjectivity (any ray that starts at the origin intersects both the interior and exterior of $K$, therefore it intersects the boundary somewhere) - but what about injectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant property of $K$ is its convexity and closedness. If a ray intersected it twice, at $x_0$ and $x_1$ with $x_0$ closer to the origin, the line segment $\overline{x_0x_1}$ would be outside of $K$ (because $\overline{O x_0}$ must be inside) contradicting its convexity since both $x_0, x_1 \in K$.

Comment: Hmm! I can see that you are right, but how do you conclude that the entire segment $\overline{x_0 x_1}$ is outside of $K$? What if it belongs to the boundary?

Comment: @Andreas If that was the case, $\overline{O x_0}$ would also belong to the boundary by convexity and thus $O\notin K^\circ$ violating the assumption.